# How to manipulate big integers for the RSA algorithm in C?

Tags: c, rsa, bignum

I want to implement the RSA cryptosystem in C. Right now I can encrypt values that fit in one byte (which I know is way too small for any security), but when I increase the size of the primes *p* and *q* (and thus of the modulus *n* = *pq*), and the size of the encrypted values, it doesn't work.

I believe I know the reasons why my code fails:

1. the value to be encrypted must be less than the *n* value (which is not always the case), and
2. the value of *n* = *pq* that I calculate is incorrect, because the real value can't be stored in the variable type that I'm using, and overflows instead.

My question is, how can I use big numbers (pack into 256 bytes, 512 bytes, etc.) and manipulate them in C? Must I use libraries (e.g. GMP)?

Comment: You might look at OpenSSL.  It had BigNumber (BN) support.  It also has RSA support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C language has no native support for arbitrary-precision integer ("bignum") arithmetic, so you will either have to use a library that provides it (I've heard that [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) is a popular choice) or write your own code to handle it.

If you choose the do-it-yourself path, I would recommend representing your numbers as arrays of some reasonably large native unsigned integer type (e.g. `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`), with [each array element representing a digit in base 2<sup>*k*</sup>](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35586/in-rsa-how-does-the-cpu-deal-with-this-huge-modulus-8192-bits), where *k* is the number of bits in the underlying native integers.

For RSA, you don't need to worry about representing negative values, since all the math is done with numbers ranging from 0 up to the RSA modulus *n*.  If you want, you can also take advantage of the upper limit *n* to fix the number of base 2<sup>*k*</sup> digits used for all the values in a particular RSA instance, so that you don't have to explicitly store it alongside each digit array.

---

Ps. Note that ["textbook RSA"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/definition-of-textbook-rsa) is not a secure encryption scheme by itself.  To make it semantically secure, you need to also include a suitable randomized padding scheme such as [OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding).  Also, padded or not, normal RSA can only encrypt messages shorter than the modulus, minus the length taken up by padding, if any.  To encrypt longer messages, the standard solution is to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), where you first encrypt the message using a symmetric encryption scheme (I would recommend [AES-SIV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297)) with a random key, and then encrypt the key with RSA.

Comment: OK, and can I use it for GPU implementation ??

Comment: Apparently, based on a quick Google search for "gmp gpu", [that may be possible.](http://hgpu.org/?p=7100) You might also consider trying the GMP fork [MPIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPIR_(mathematics_software)) instead. Or, of course, writing your own bignum arithmetic implementation.

Comment: Well, when using libraries, please make sure it support some necessary operator (shift bit, modulo, divide) and negative number (the extended euclidean may require)a, also for better performance it should use karatsuba multiplication. Just some my experience. Hope it help. @wolfgunner